# Implementing all read api with a intercepting filter using Servicestack.Ormlite

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

To elaborate what I try to achieve with servicestack.ormlite. Imagine that a franchise business has some branches, each branch has system and local database, all of these database are replicating each other. In the system, each model is with a property called store_id like below.

```
public class UserEntity : EntityBase
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string user_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public int role { get; set; }
}
public class EntityBase
{
    public int store_id {get;set;}
    public bool is_delete {get;set;}
}
```

We have 40+ entity and repos, is there any way to have all servicestack.ormlite read api filtered by store_id in one action instead of coding repo by repo ? I've a abstract repobase from which all repos are derived. And some repos needs to read all data across different store_id.

[image]

any help is much appreciated !!

Comment: Please go through [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as it's extremely vague as what the answer for this question is supposed to be. It sounds like you want to magically DRY up some repetitive code using a hypothetical framework feature, but there's no example of the repetitive code you want to DRY and what the proposed FX feature should look and behave like. My initial impression is that you should be first leveraging C# lang features to DRY code before looking for a magical fx feature, but without any example code it's impossible to provide any guidance.

Comment: @mythz, apologies if I didn't explain my question clearly. I've attached my repobase.

Comment: all repos inherits from the repobase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is still unclear on what answer it wants, the screenshot says it doesn't know which API to use to filter by store_id but your screenshot includes 2 different examples of filtering by `store_id`?

```
db.Where<T>(new { store_id = _store_id });

db.Where<T>("store_id", _store_id);
```

Both of which should work. Although I'd recommend using the Typed version when possible, you can also use `nameof()` instead of magic strings:

```
db.Where<T>(nameof(EntityBase.store_id), _store_id);
```

Maybe you're after different examples of doing the same thing inside a generic repo?

You can also query using a typed `SqlExpression<T>`:

```
var q = db.From<T>().Where(x => (x as EntityBase).store_id == _store_id);
var all = db.Select(q);
```

Or if you want to combine it with an additional typed expression:

```
var q = db.From<T>().Where(x => (x as EntityBase).store_id == _store_id);
var filtered = db.Select(q.And(expr));
```

Since you're already using generic constraints, you can also add a constraint that the entity must be a `EntityBase` as well, e.g:

```
class RepoBase<T> where T : EntityBase, new() { ... }
```

That way you can query without casting, e.g:

```
var q = db.From<T>().Where(x => x.store_id == _store_id);
var all = db.Select(q);
```

and

```
var q = db.From<T>().Where(x => x.store_id == _store_id);
var filtered = db.Select(q.And(expr));
```

Comment: var all = db.Select(q); var filterd = db.Select(q.And(expr)); this helps me a lot. I don't know I can do it this way with servicestack.  thanks for your answer. and apologies again for asking a vague question. I will make the question more understandable later.